# Loading an aggregate with a field other than its id from an event sourcing event store

Tags: java, microservices, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am diving deeper into CQRS and event sourcing architecture. I am a bit confused about loading an aggregate (write model) into my application.

I push all my events to my Kafka event bus and also save the read projection in my application local database as events. While I don't have any problems loading my aggregate to its latest state from my event store, I am at trouble when I need to find an aggregate or validate commands to be applied on it by something other then its ID, which may change over time (e.g. email address). I can, however, find older events with old email addresses by querying my read model database with a query like `Where mail = given_mail`.

Maybe my concept is wrong and I should publish event only to event bus and store Materialized Models in Database (event if it is command parts)?
Maybe while my Query part is kafka-listner and create ReadOnly Projections I should use the same repository to fetch data from Read-Database even on Command side?

I am considering which approach is better/correct and if you have any documents about it feel free to share with me :)

I tried to find a out of articles about event sourcing.

Comment: Is the requirement that you can lookup the aggregate by a previously used mail address or only the current one?
In any case, I would opt to create an 'internal' projection, aka Materialized Model, to map the mail address to the AggregateID.